# How to make a document such as this image?

Tags: packages

[image]

I am relatively new at LaTeX and I was wondering how to make a document such as this one.

Comment: Check out the [tcolorbox](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tcolorbox) package.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a `just-do-it-for-me` question.

Comment: @raaja This is a fully legitimate question. Mohamed asks for advice, he does not ask anybody to do the layout for him.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually easy to make. It is just tcolorboxes.
For example:
your boxes have this minimal code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}
\tcbuselibrary{fitting}
\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{0,163,243}

\newtcboxfit{mybox}[1]{colback=blue!5!white,colframe=white,left=1mm,top=1mm,bottom=1mm,
right=1mm,boxsep=0mm,width=3.5cm,height=7cm,nobeforeafter,
before upper=\textcolor{myblue!75!white}{\rule{1.5mm}{1.5mm}}\ ,
fonttitle=\bfseries,adjusted title=#1,fit algorithm=#1}

\begin{document}
\mybox{fontsize}{\lipsum[2]}
\end{document}
```

It is inspired by the tcolorbox Pack­age doc­u­men­ta­tion page 430 and looks like this:
[image]

with \hfill you can have two or more next to each other.

When you look at newtcboxfit, you see a `width=3.5cm,height=7cm`-part. there you change the size of your boxes, which means, you need to create a new `\newtcboxfit{mybox2}`. The rest is up to you. It is simple the tcolorbox.